# Thousand comma separator not working for an updating Input value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';


@Pipe({name: 'decimalComma'})

export class DecimalCommaPipe  implements  PipeTransform {
    constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe){}
    addCommas(nStr) {
        const thousands = /\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g
        return nStr.replace(thousands, ',');
    }
    transform(value: any, ...args: any[]) {
       const commaVal =  this.currencyPipe.transform(value, '', '', `0.0-0`, '');
       const replacedVal =  commaVal.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
       return this.addCommas(replacedVal);
    }
}
```

and in the component.ts

```
 maxAllowedLength() :void {
    this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
      const investLength = data?.investmentAmount?.toString();
      const monthlyContriLength = data?.monthlyContributionAmount?.toString();
      if(investLength.length) {
        let formattedVal = this.cp.transform(data?.investmentAmount)
        this.formGroup.patchValue({investmentAmount: formattedVal, emitEvent: false, editModelToViewChange: true})
      }

      if(monthlyContriLength.length > 6) {
        debugger;
        let formattedVal = parseInt(monthlyContriLength.substring(0, monthlyContriLength.length-1))
        this.formGroup.patchValue({monthlyContributionAmount: formattedVal})
      }
    })
```

This code works but only for a value that is passed in at once.
I have an input box that brings value one by one and the code doesnt update it.
I tried adding the addCommas function because the currencyPipe was also not updating the "COMMAS" for the values that were coming in.

On every change detection to the value the pipe is triggered.

I am using this in an Angular Pipe

Comment: would help if you showed how you called it so we can try and recreate the error to help debug

Comment: That's not a Pipe, that's just a function. If you want help, help us help you by giving us a nice explanation, enough code to understand and reproduce the issue and its context. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why would this function update an input box?

Comment: not really the best idea to update it as user types but you probably want to remove them `return str.replace(/,/,'').replace(thousands, ',');`

Comment: Why don't you use the `DecimalPipe` of Angular? It will provide for you the correct separator for any locale

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina I tried using it but it wouldnt update it, I have updated my question can you please have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You can add a keyup event on the input field to run the function.

Comment: its being called on every change detection to the value and I have updated the post with more code